# Application for filtering database for the short period of time

Tags: c++, sql, algorithm, performance, data-structures

I need to create an application that would allow me to get phone numbers of users with specific conditions as fast as possible. For example we've got 4 columns in sql table(region, income, age [and 4th with the phone number itself]). I want to get phone numbers from the table with specific region and income. Just make a sql query won't help because it takes significant amount of time. Database updates 1 time per day and I have some time to prepare data as I wish.

**The question is:** How would you make the process of getting phone numbers with specific conditions as fast as possible. O(1) in the best scenario. Consider storing values from sql table in RAM for the fastest access.

I came up with the following idea:

1. For each phone number create smth like a bitset. 0 if the particular condition is false and 1 if the condition is true. But I'm not sure I can implement it for columns with not boolean values.
2. Create a vector with phone numbers.
3. Create a vector with phone numbers' bitsets.
4. To get phone numbers - iterate for the 2nd vector and compare bitsets with required one.

It's not O(1) at all. And I still don't know what to do about not boolean columns. I thought maybe it's possible to do something good with std::unordered_map (all phone numbers are unique) or improve my idea with vector and masks.

P.s. SQL table consumes 4GB of memory and I can store up to 8GB in RAM. The're 500 columns.

Comment: Are you saying that you can query on any of those 500 columns?

Comment: The program shall provide phone numbers for any request, yes

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get phone numbers from the table with specific region and income.

You would create indexes in the database on `(region, income)`.  Let the database do the work.

Comment: How would you implement this and what about memory? There're 2^500 combinations of queries. Like (region), (region, income), (region, age), (region, income, age), (income, age) etc. but w/ 500 columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it to be fast I think you should consider ElasticSearch. Think of every phone in the DB as a doc with properties (your columns).
You will need to reindex the table once a day (or in realtime) but when it's time to search you just use the filter of ElasticSearch to find the results.

Another option is to have an index for every column. In this case the engine will do an Index Merge to increase performance. I would also consider using MEMORY Tables. In case you write to this table - consider having a read replica just for reads.
To optimize your table - save your queries somewhere and add index(for multiple columns) just for the top X popular searches depends on your memory limitations.
You can use use NVME as your DB disk (if you can't load it to memory)